# How to get the index of the selected item in Ext.form.field.ComboBox?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How can I get the index of the selected item for xtype combo in ExtJS4 ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'index'? A combo is bound to a store, which primarily uses ids, rather than indexes. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using attaching an event handler to the **beforeselect** event. Look ate the documentation for that event here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-beforeselect